# JDBC insertin String,Date and duration values to table

Tags: string, date, jdbc, duration

I've been trying to insert String, Date(now) and duration to the table.

Here is my code: At the args section (at the end) "app.insert("name", "date_added","path", "duration");" **those values I mentioned as " date_added and duration" it wants me to convert them into String with an error.** How can I prevent this happening and let the code enter date(now) and duration to app.insert section? [image]

```
package xxxxx;

import java.sql.*;

public class SAMPLE_SOUND {

    private Connection connect() {

        String url = "jdbc:sqlite:neural.db";
        Connection conn = null;
        try {
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        return conn;
    }
    public void insert(String name,Date date_added, String path, Time duration){
        String sql= " INSERT INTO SAMPLE_SOUND(name,date_added,path,duration) VALUES(?,?,?,?)";

        try(Connection conn = this.connect();
            PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql)){
            pstmt.setString(1,name);
            pstmt.setDate(2, date_added);
            pstmt.setString(3,path);
            pstmt.setTime(4, duration);

            pstmt.executeUpdate();
        } catch (SQLException e){
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SAMPLE_SOUND app = new SAMPLE_SOUND();
        app.insert("name", "date_added","path", "duration");
    }
}
```

Comment: Slightly aside, using SQL TIME datatype for a duration seems to go against the intentions, though I cannot readily tell you what you should use instead. TIME is for a time of day, not for a duration.

Comment: The classes `java.sql.Date` and `java.sql.Time` are long outdated and replaced by [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/), which is much nicer to work with. For date added, you will want to use a `LocalDate`, and provided you’ve got a fairly new JDBC driver, you can insert it into your database through `pstmt.setObject(2, localDateAdded);`. For the duration it’s less clear, since the `Duration` class is for a duration, while `LocalTime` matches the SQL TIME datatype best.

Answer (score 1):

> it wants me to convert them into String with an error

No, not at all. It signals that you're trying to pass strings as arguments, elthough the method expects a Date and a Time. The **correct** fix is of course to pass a Date and a Time. But IntelliJ doesn't know that, and it suggests that maybe you actually do want to pass Strings, and the arguments types should then be changed to String.

Remember, you are the smart developer. It's up to you to decide what to do.

Please respect the Java naming conventions.